# MapView iOS 6 Mapview- Custom Trace Line

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have got my code to trace a path of GPS locations for a bus route. This works fine, but im trying to create a custom line, to make it look better than a bland stright line.

I went to create a line with a stoke but whenever i change the stoke, the whole line changes, and the fill color doesnt change anything.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"routeLines"];
        if ([array containsObject:overlay]) {
            // create a MKPolylineView with the right colour and display it
            MKPolylineView *lineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:      (MKPolyline *)overlay];
            lineView.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            lineView.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            lineView.lineWidth = 5;

            overlayView = lineView;
            break;
```